# Why is the intersection towards infinity an empty set?

Tags: set-theory

I have very minimal background in set theory and proofs so could someone please explain intuitively (to a layperson) why this is the case?

Let $X_n = \{n+1, n+2,..., 2n\}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N^+}$. Then

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n = \emptyset$$

Comment: What are $X_1$ and $X_2$?  ... If you can find those and understand the definition, you can answer your own question.  If not, I'm not sure a stand-alone answer will suffice.

Comment: Well $X_3 = \{4,5,6\}$ where $X_{10} = \{11,12,13,...., 20\}$.  Can those two sets have any elements in common?  If those two *can't* then how can *all* sets have something in common?

Comment: If $w\in \cap^\infty X_n$ then $w\in X_k$ for all $k$.  That means that 1) $w$ is a positive natural number.  And for *EVERY* (and I mean *EVERY*) possible natural number we have $k+1 \le w \le 2k$.  Is it possible that there is any such natural number?  ... And for a third reason..... Notice that $n \not \in X_n$.  So for any natural number $w$ we have $w\not \in X_w$.  And if $w \not \in X_w$ then $w \not \in \cap^\infty X_n$.

Comment: $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ is by definition the set of the natural numbers that are in all the $X_n$. Specifically, a natural number $x$ is in it if and only if, for all $n\in\Bbb N^+$, $n< x\le 2n$. However, for any given $x$ this condition fails for $n=x$. So no $x$ is in it.

Comment: $X_1=\{2\}$ and $X_2=\{3,4\}.$ So $X_1\cap X_2$ is the empty set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n\ne \phi$, then we have some $x\in X_1, X_2$. $X_1=\{2\}$ and $X_2=\{3, 4\}$.

Clearly, there is no intersection between these two sets.